# Access pop-up window button via API in C#

Tags: c#, api

I'm building a plug-in in a structural design software and I'm using C# to access the API. All the geometric definitions, materials, verifications etc are fine. I use a button in the app to run the calculations. When the calcs are done the attached window pops up.

[image]

As part of a recursive process I'm trying to automatically press "Yes" from the API using SendMessage but I can't make it work. The code looks like this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpclassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    int WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "Autodesk Robot Structural Analysis Professional 2014");
    SendMessage(WindowToFind, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
```

Does anyone know a better way to approach this (maybe mouse_event)?

Help will be much appreciated.

Best,

Comment: You might also want to post or see if you can talk to the people making the software - ideally there should be a way to suppress the message dialog from coming up at all.

Comment: Thanks Derek. In the specific software I managed to do it but I wanted to investigate a generic approach that can be used on different APIs.

Comment: If you are interested in ui automation - the place to start is probably the AutomationElement class and uispy.  I do programming by voice, and most of the ui automation stuff I do uses AutomationElement, etc.  See my answer below for some of the things to look into.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, I'd give a few options:

1. Use Windows API plus the AutomationElement class.  You should be able to do the "Invoke" automation pattern to click the button.  For me, this would be the preferred way to do this.
2. Use Windows API plus SendInput to use keyboard (or mouse) to click the button.

Look into the AutomationElement class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You will probably want to find "uispy" or some other utility for looking at AutomationElements.  Another option is to wait for the window title to change to what you are looking for - assuming that the dialog has a different window title than the main window.

Some helpful apis are:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();


/// <summary>
/// gets the window title of the foreground window
/// </summary>
public static string GetWindowTitle()
{
   return GetWindowText( GetForegroundWindow() );
}

public static string GetWindowText( IntPtr hWnd )
{
   int length = GetWindowTextLength( hWnd );
   StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder( length + 1 );
   GetWindowText( hWnd, text, text.Capacity );
   return text.ToString();
}

[DllImport( "user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto )]
public static extern int GetWindowTextLength( IntPtr hwnd );

[DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
private static extern int GetWindowText( IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount );
```

You could use keyboard input to send the keys:

You could check out this:

http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx for the start page for ui automation

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but if anyone comes accross this in the future:

```
// switch Interactive flag off to avoid any questions that need user interaction in Robot
        iapp.Interactive = 0;
```